# Avoid salary requirement for exempt employee by changing job title?

Tags: software-industry, united-states, california

I'm a software engineer working in California. I've been working at my current company for about 5 years and am generally quite happy. Recently, management has been interested in making me an exempt employee. However, I make significantly less than the minimum salary threshold which is about $90K in the state of CA according to CA.gov ([https://www.dir.ca.gov/...](https://www.dir.ca.gov/dlse/Glossary.asp?Button1=E#employee%20in%20the%20computer%20software%20field)) and Society for Human Resource Management ([https://www.shrm.org/...](https://www.shrm.org/resourcesandtools/tools-and-samples/hr-qa/pages/california-minsalarycomputerexemption.aspx)), which states:

> California  Labor Code Section 515.5 provides that certain computer software employees are exempt from overtime pay if particular criteria are met. One of the required criteria is that the employee's rate of pay not be less than a certain threshold dollar amount. Effective Jan. 1, 2018, an employer can choose to pay an exempt computer software employee an hourly rate of at least $43.58 per hour or a salary of at least $7,565.85 per month ($90,790.07 annually).

and so they've been considering changing my job title so as to avoid this requirement.

I think I'm quite fairly compensated and wouldn't feel like I'm being taken advantage of if I don't get a huge raise. However, it seems a bit dodgy since my duties wouldn't change at all. I'd be a software engineer in all but title. Can they actually do this?

Comment: There is no salary requirement based on job title.

Comment: @paparazzo true, but there do appear to be salary requirements based on duties at least in CA

Comment: This might be easier for folks to read than the PDF: https://www.dir.ca.gov/dlse/Glossary.asp?Button1=E#employee%20in%20the%20computer%20software%20field

Comment: "Can they actually do this?" sounds like a case for https://law.stackexchange.com/, which is better than here for questions of legality.

Comment: @DavidThornley This meets the criteria of a question that a HR manager in jurisdiction would be able to answer without consulting a lawyer.

Comment: @alicebob  Changing titles to try to skirt labor laws is an old loophole that would have long since been closed in most jurisdictions.  My father-in-law was hired as an "Assistant Manager" at a department store in the 1960s.  His job was counting stock and filling shelves.  Partway through his employment there the store was forced to remove the exempt status for everyone with non-managerial duties.

Comment: Why do they suddenly want to make you exempt? Do you work a lot of overtime right now? If you are not working a lot of overtime, and they begin to require more and more, because you are now exempt, your current compensation per hour will go way down. So even though you feel fairly compensated right now, with having to do that much overtime you'll probably feel a lot different.

Comment: There might be other reasons for changing your title.  Although it appears that California does not restrict use of the title "software engineer", your company might also do business in states that do.  It's safest not to call yourself an engineer, or describe your work as engineering, unless you are actually a licensed professional engineer.  (And I'm confident you wouldn't be asking a question about "significantly less than the [90k] salary threshold" if you were a PE in California)

Comment: @BenVoigt my direct manager has stated (verbally) that this would be the reason to change the title. Also, I fail to see what "danger" there is in calling oneself an engineer is - if you have a degree in computer/software/mechanical/etc engineering then it seems that you ought to be an engineer

Comment: Well in Texas, where I work, people with a degree in engineering (and it must be ABET accredited) can use the title of "graduate engineer" but the license is required for any other combination, including "engineer" alone, "software engineer", offers to perform "engineering" etc.  Your engineering curriculum should have explained the path to PE to you and warned you that such restrictions exist.  Where you are in California, you can call yourself a "software engineer", but someone with an EE degree and no license cannot use "electrical engineer".

Answer (score 8):

> and so they've been considering changing my job title so as to avoid this requirement.

*California Labor Code Section 515.5* doesn’t say anything of job title, only job function “computer science employee”, if your job duty meets the qualifications of the law then that description would apply to you.  In order for you become, an exempted employee, you would have to be paid more or at the required pay level per the CA law since you are working in California.

Your employer can’t “get out of the requirements”, because the only way you are an exempted employee, is if your being paid at the level defined by the law.

> Labor Code Section 515.5 provides that certain computer software employees shall be exempt from the requirement that an overtime rate of compensation be paid pursuant to Labor Code Section 510, if certain criteria are met. One of the required criteria is that the employee’s hourly rate of pay not be less than a certain threshold dollar amount. The Division of Labor Statistics and Research is responsible for adjusting this pay rate on October 1 of each year to be effective on January 1 of the following year by an amount equal to the percentage increase in the California Consumer Price Index for Urban Wage Earners and Clerical Workers. Below is the history of this required hourly pay rate.

Source: https://www.dir.ca.gov/dlse/LC515-5.pdf

Comment: Even the federal law doesn’t care about job titles, only job duties, your employer simply cannot make you exempted unless your duties change significantly.  If they do claim your exempted, without increasing your pay, I would contact CA labor board and/or a labor attorney.

Comment: I have slightly adjusted my answer since I don't know which job duties, are actually covered by the California law.  However, since the question was specifically about the pay with regards to the law, I am not going to attempt to parse through dozens of different California labor code sections.  *I feel I have addressed the main topic of the question.*